# how to sort a "group by" clause so the value returned is the last

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

i have a query where i want to get the last item in a joined table, but i want to filter on that join. when i use a "group by" clause it seems to return the first value, not the last. how do i get the last instead?

for example, i have an Order table and an OrderStatus table, i want to get an Order with a specific status but only if it is the last OrderStatus...

OrderStatus table...

```
ID | OrderID | Status
---------------------
1  | 1       | cart
2  | 1       | pending
3  | 1       | paid
4  | 2       | cart
5  | 2       | pending
```

So for Status = pending I only want to return OrderID 2 and not OrderID 1. here's what I tried:

```
select * from `Order` where `ID` in 
(select `OrderID` from `OrderStatus` where `status` like 'pending' 
group by `OrderID` order by `ID` DESC)
```

but it returns both Orders. the `order by` clause is ignored, i guess it applies to the query after grouping and not before. How can I get OrderStatus = pending only if it is the last one?

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using, it makes a difference to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `orderid`s whose last status is "pending" by using a `having` clause:

```
select o.*
from Orders o
where o.id in (select os.orderid
               from orderstatus os
               group by os.orderid
               having max(os.id) = max(case when os.status = 'pending' then os.id end)
              );
```

The comparison works by calculating the largest `id` and comparing it to the largest `id` for "pending".

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly you will get the last one with simple Limit 1 after ordering like that:

select * from `Order` where `ID` in 
(select `OrderID` from `OrderStatus` where `status` like 'pending' 
group by `OrderID` order by `ID` DESC **LIMIT 1**)

But im not sure tho.